# Error: App id contains a reserved word, or is not a valid identifier

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I just create a project from cli using command :

```
cordova create Event com.kamlesh.event
```

and error comes like :

```
Error: App id contains a reserved word, or is not a valid identifier.
```

can any one describe it! Thanks.

Comment: Use `cordova create "Event" com.kamlesh.event "Event"`

Comment: Getting same error

Comment: Alright then try to create with other name then reserved and change afterwards from `config.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it generally happens when the name of the app you want to create contains invalid characters. 
It also happens when you  create a new Cordova project and seed it with a code in a certain location but the `PATH` contains invalid chars, exp:

```
cordova create demo --copy-from=/Users/test/Downloads/cordova place/c4/my_demo
```

Pay attention to *cordova place* with the space causing the problem.